# How to pick first three elements of an array and construct a comma seperated String

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have an array of fruits. I want to construct a comma separated string of this array for first three elements only. Right now, I am constructing a comma separated string for all.

```
var fruits = [];

fruits.push("Banana");
fruits.push("Orange");
fruits.push("Apple");
fruits.push("Mango");
fruits.push("Orange");
fruits.push("Papya");
fruits.push("CALAPPLE");

var result = fruits.toString();

alert(result);
```

Could you please let me know how to achieve this? This is [my jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qna8sbf7/1/).

Answer (score 7):

Slice the array with [`Array.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), which will return a new array with only the sliced elements and join them with [`Array.prototype.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), like this

```
console.log(fruits.slice(0, 3).join(", "));
// Banana, Orange, Apple
```

Here, we say that start slicing from index zero, till three. The last element will not be included in the slice. So, from the index zero, we get the elements at index zero, one and two.

---

If you don't want to create a new array with `slice`, you can just use a simple `for` loop and do it like this

```
var result = "";
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i += 1) {
    result += fruits[i] + ", ";
}
result += fruits[i];

console.log(result);
// Banana, Orange, Apple
```